# Custom dataset os.path.join () returns type error

Tags: pytorch

I am writing custom dataset but it returns type error when I am merging root directory `path` with pandas `iloc` of image name in csv file:

```
 img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index,0])
```

error:  `TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'int64'`

I have tried converting the annotation.iloc to string type but it's still giving me the same error.

[csvfile with filenames and labels:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mme37.png)

custom dataset class:

```
class patientdataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):  
            self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
            self.root_dir = root_dir
            self.transform = transform



    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index,0])  
        image= np.array(np.load(img_path)) 
        y_label = torch.tensor(self.annotations.iloc[index, 1]).long()


        if self.transform:
            imagearrays = self.transform(image)
            image = imagearrays[None, :, :, :]
            imaget = np.transpose(image, (0, 2, 1, 3))
            image = imaget


        return (image, y_label)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your dataset (attached csv file), `pd.read_csv(csv_file)` produces dataframe with 3 columns: 1st for index, 2nd for filename, and 3rd for label. And this `img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index,0])` line is not working because `iloc[index, 0]` is about the 1st column, it will extract index data and not a file name, and `join` expects to get 2 strings, that's why you are getting `TypeError`.

Based on your `csv` file example, you should do:

```py
class patientdataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):  
            self.annotations = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
            self.root_dir = root_dir
            self.transform = transform



    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.annotations)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.annotations.iloc[index, 1])  # 1 - for file name (2nd column)  
        image= np.array(np.load(img_path)) 
        y_label = torch.tensor(self.annotations.iloc[index, 2]).long()  # 2 - for label (3rd column)


        if self.transform:
            imagearrays = self.transform(image)
            image = imagearrays[None, :, :, :]
            imaget = np.transpose(image, (0, 2, 1, 3))
            image = imaget


        return (image, y_label)
```

Comment: Thankyou for the detailed answer, I thought the the index col doesn't get counted so I started off with 0 and 1, but thanks for the idea. But it still gives me the same error :/

Comment: What about  `root_dir`? is it a string?

Comment: it is, I explicitly defined it as string.